# Onmouseover ,Onmouseout attributes were not working in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried all possible ways for this highlighting a row in gridview, I can't be able to achive this.I tried direct CSS-Classes,javascript. Pls note me where I made a mistake. Thanks in advance...

```
protected void test_databound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='hand';this.style.background='#D1DDF1';";
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.background='#EFF3FB';";

        //e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "javascript:SetMouseOver(this)"; 
        //e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "javascript:SetMouseOut(this)";

        //e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "className='highlighted1'");
        //e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=''");
        //e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");

        //e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor='#000000'");
        //e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor='#000000'");
        //e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");


        //e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.originalstyle=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#000000'");
        //e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=this.originalstyle");
        //e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
    }


    //e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmousedown", "IsMouseDown(this,true)");
    //e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseup", "IsMouseDown(this,true)");
    //e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "HighlightRow(this,true)");
    //foreach (GridViewRow grow in gvCatalogList.Rows)
    //{
    //    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmousedown", "IsMouseDown(this)");
    //    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseup", "IsMouseDown(this)");


    //    grow.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "highlight(this, true);";
    //    grow.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "highlight(this, false);";
    //    HttpResponse myHttpResponse = Response;
    //    HtmlTextWriter myHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(myHttpResponse.Output);
    //    grow.Attributes.AddAttributes(myHtmlTextWriter);
    //}
}
```

This is my design page

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCatalogList" GridLines="None" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
PageSize="5" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging_gvCatalogList" 
OnRowDataBound="test_databound">
<FooterStyle CssClass="pagination-flickr" />
<PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-flickr" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Estimation ID">
<HeaderStyle Wrap="true" Width="10%" />
<ItemTemplate>
<div style="width: 40px; white-space: normal">
<asp:Label ID="label1" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectEstimationVersionID") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenEstimationID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ProjectEstimationID") %>' />
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code and description, I think you want to add a highlight effect to the hover row of your GridView.

If so, I suggest you to use the following code to achieve:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
         e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "currentcolor=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='yellow',this.style.fontWeight='';");


         e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=currentcolor,this.style.fontWeight='';");
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply vignesh.Actually i tried this code also its not not working. Am i need to enable or disable any properties?

Comment: @VR46 I have worked with this,it's working for me. Please post your gridview design code

Comment: Excellent Solution -- This also works on a calendar view by replacing "e.Row" with "e.Cell" on the CalendarName_DayRender event.

Answer (score 0):

check now..replace cursor='hand' with cursor='pointer'

```
protected void test_databound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
       e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.background='#D1DDF1';";
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.background='#EFF3FB';";
    }
}
```