# Gridview row hover not changing

Tags: c#, gridview

Tried using the below code in grid view row data bound event, still not use. Any can suggest what I am doing wrong.

Gridview Row background color not getting changed.

```
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'; this.style.textDecoration = 'underline'");
e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.textDecoration = 'none'");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796262/onmouseover-onmouseout-attributes-were-not-working-in-gridview

Comment: Tried all solution like using css, javascript, jquery still no use. what could be possible problem of area I need to check?